# how to display "Must change password" using jsp and servlet during the first logon of user

Tags: jsp, servlets

"Must change password" should be displayed when the user logon for the first time and needs to change it.. how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a "must change password" column in the user database and set it to true when a new account is set up (or the system creates a temporary password for some other reason or whenever some other policy indicates the user needs a new password).

Comment: @soul: for what part exactly? If you stucks at a specific step, you've got to ask a specific question about exactly that step. This is not a "Do my job for me" place.